# Minimax not working and not giving out a best move(python)

Tags: python, minimax

I have been trying to use a minimax algorithm for a game of connect 4 then implementing alpha beta pruning later to make it stronger. But I am running into the issue where the computer is not returning the best move it will just run through minimax 5 times then give up and not return best move. I'm not really sure how to deal with this issue. Here is the relevant code:
Note: Running at a low depth on purpose because my computer can't handle a lot of calculating and just for testing purposes atm

```
import pygame as p
import sys 
import math
from time import sleep

board = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]

def gravity(col):
    for r in range(5, -1, -1):
        if board[r][col] == 0:
            return r

def place_counter(playe, mousex, mousey):
    global colour
    if playe == 1:
        colour = (255, 255, 0)
    if playe == 2:
        colour = (255, 0, 0)
    xbox = math.floor(mousex / 100)
    ybox = math.floor(mousey / 100)
    row = gravity(xbox)
    board[row][xbox] = playe
    print_board(board)
    p.draw.circle(screen, colour, (50 + 100 * xbox, 50 + 100 * row), 40)

def c_move(b_move):
    place_counter(2, b_move, b_move)

def comp_move():
    best_score = - 10
    best_move = 0
    for key in range(len(board)):
        print(key)
        if board[key][gravity(key)] == 0:
            board[key][gravity(key)] = bot
            score = minimax(0, False)
            board[key][gravity(key)] = 0
            if score > best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_move = key
    if best_move != 0:
        c_move(best_move)
        print_board(board)

def minimax(depth, isMaximizing):
    if isMaximizing:
        best_score = -800
        for key in range(len(board)):
            if board[key][gravity(key)] == 0:
                board[key][gravity(key)] = bot
                score = minimax(depth + 1, False)
                board[key][gravity(key)] = 0
                if score > best_score:
                    best_score = score
                if depth == 5:
                    best_score = score
            return best_score
    else:
        best_score = 800
        for key in range(len(board)):
            if board[key][gravity(key)] == 0:
                board[key][gravity(key)] = player
                score = minimax(depth + 1, True)
                board[key][gravity(key)] = 0
                if score < best_score:
                    best_score = score
                if depth == 5:
                    best_score = score
        return best_score

while game_over is False:
    for event in p.event.get():
        if event.type == p.QUIT:
            p.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == SCREEN_UPDATE:
            p.display.update()
        if event.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if turn % 2 != 0:
                player1_move()
                winning_move(1)
                turn += 1
            else:
                comp_move()
                winning_move(2)
                turn += 1
```

Any suggestions are very welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to provide an evaluation function that estimates the score at the leaves of your search tree (when depth==5).
As it is now, all possible sequences of moves lead to either 800 or -800, so effectively the first move will be chosen every time.